# Clojure ClassCastException does not show 'on what'

Tags: clojure

I'm quite new to Clojure. The stack traces are not what I am used to with Java or Scala, but usually I can get by, until now. I am running a simple console program that starts, runs, prints some output, then this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException, compiling: <removed by me!>
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7142)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

What is the most likely cause? Does this sort of thing happen to more experienced Clojure programmers too? (rhetorical question). Are there ways of being more careful to avoid this sort of thing? And how do I quickly get back on track? I can put trace in and work out exactly when this event happened, but I'm wondering if there is a better way of going about it...

Comment: Does the stacktrace really end with `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException`? That seems quire surprising to me. You would expect one of the caused-by exceptions to include a from/to class that failed casting.

Comment: It's only once in a while I get one of these uninformative stacktraces.  (Not this one, but one that doesn't tell me anything I can use.)  Then I usually start guessing and adding print statements.  Or you could do it right, and use a debugger.  Doesn't happen that often.

Comment: @amalloy. Yes. The console starts off with `>lein run` and `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException` is on the last line after the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pos?` has to be asked on something that is a number.

```
(pos? cannot-be-a-vector)
```

That was it for this case!